# How can I convert a BufferedImage object into an InputStream or a BLOB?

Tags: java, blob, inputstream

I am trying to store an image uploaded by the user into the database with a `LONGBLOB` attribute... I ran into a problem with a `PreparedStatement` that has two methods to set a blob which are:

`public void setBinaryStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x)`

`public void setBlob(int parameterIndex, Blob x)`

`public void setBlob(int parameterIndex, InputStream inputStream)`

Now the problem is I have a `BufferedImage` object which must be converted into `Blob` or `InputStream` to upload...

How can I do this without losing the original image format or quality?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> ***How can I do this without losing the original image format or quality?***

You need to save it using some appropriate (lossless) format. The [png format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) is one option.

The [`ImageIO`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class has methods for writing out an image to an output stream.

Here's a complete example of how you get hold of an `InputStream` from which you can read the PNG-representation of the content of a `BufferedImage`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Thanks Csujo and @aioobe for quick answers....but in both cases i have to manage also the incoming format of image...is there no other way to do the same thing without that format conversion ??

Comment: How do you receive this "incoming" image?

Comment: By choosing image using file chooser

Comment: Then use a FileInputStream to save the original byte array along side with the buffered image. To the extent of my knowledge, there's no way of "recovering" the exact sequence of bytes that was once used to generate the content of a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image,"jpg", bas);
byte[] bytes = bas.toByteArray();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

Don't forget to check the second ImageIO.write parameter to your required image format (e.g. "jpg", "bmp", "png").

Answer (score 1):

Write functions to serialize/unserialize the BufferedImage
to/from a `byte []` and use classes `ByteArrayInputStream` and
`ByteArrayOutputStream`.

You probably need to serialize the image type, width, height
and the image pixel values (obtained with `BufferedImage.getRGB(x, y)`).

The alternative is to call `ImageIO.write(image, "png", outStream)`
to convert the image to PNG format and write it to a
`ByteArrayOutputStream`.  There is an equivalent `ImageIO.read(inputStream)`
method to read the image from a `ByteArrayInputStream`.
There is some processing overhead in converting to/from PNG.
But PNG is a compressed image format and you will save a lot
of space compared with storing the images uncompressed.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate more the first method?

Answer (score 0):

To create a Blob:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);
Blob blFile = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(baos.toByteArray());
```